# Why wont my CakeEmail send?

Tags: cakephp, cakeemail

I have the following function being called from my view.ctp file after a form button is pressed. However nothing is being recieved. Any advice?

```
public function email(){
// ============Email================//

/* SMTP Options */
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
    'port' => '465',
    'timeout' => '30',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'username' => 'email1@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'password1',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);

// sending/receiver details for email

$this->Email->template = 'resetpw';
$this->Email->from = 'Cafe <email1@gmail.com>';
$this->Email->to = 'Andrew <email2@gmail.com';
$this->Email->subject = 'Junto Cafe: Password reset';
$this->Email->sendAs = 'both';
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
$this->set('ms', $ms);
$this->Email->send();
$this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);

// after sending, display a notification

$this->Session->setFlash(__('Check Your Email To Reset your password', true) , 'alert-box', array(
    'class' => 'alert-success'
));

// ============EndEmail=============//
}
```

Comment: was any error popped out? did you get any error log in app/log/error ?

Comment: are you add App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

Comment: Thanks Vikram that was the problem thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Forgot to add

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');